# Using Fiddler as proxy for HttpWebRequest requires Fiddler to be running

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I have a web application that I'm developing that makes a lot of HttpWebRequests. In order to make debugging them easier, I've set up the following in my web.config;

```
<system.net>
     <defaultProxy>
         <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:9999" />
      </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This allows all of my HttpWebRequests to proxy through Fiddler. The problem is I need to have Fiddler running in order to have my app work correctly.

Ideally, I would like to have it proxy through Fiddler when Fiddler is running, and not proxy at all when Fiddler is not running without having to change my web.config each time.

Comment: Your client should use a proxy not your server app. So don't point the server side to fiddler.

Comment: @lboshuizen - I'm not exactly sure how your suggestion can be used - clearly if server makes requests to other resources there is no way client will even know about them...

Comment: @lboshuizen Debugging network calls server side when developing locally is a huge win.

Comment: You can ping the Fiddler's url directly first (in app start?) and depending on response set default proxy via code... Also I would not even try - if somehow the setting gets into production environment it would be way to easy to listen for all server responses...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I thought of this myself, the problem is Fiddlers address is 127.0.0.1:9999. Pinging 127.0.0.1 always comes back positive. And you cant ping for port numbers so this doesnt do what I need.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've been putting my proxy attempts behind a DEV compiler flag so I'm not worries about anything accidentally making it into production.

Comment: "ping" in general sense, sorry... Make web request to "127.0.0.1:9999" and check if response contains Fiddler echo response.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's not a bad idea.  I can definitely try that.

Comment: @ChrisLees true, but debugging with a client you can't control makes no sense. So still (this case): fiddler client-side

Comment: @lboshuizen Lets say I have a 3rd party service I'm connecting to that I dont have control over.  This service returns XML.  On the server side of my app I need to call that service and deserialize the XML into an object that I can work with.  After setting it up and having it work for a while, suddenly the app doesnt deserialize the XML anymore. Dot net deserialization being what it is, it's hard to find exactly where the issue is.  Getting the raw xml from the service in Fiddler is super handy when debugging that.

Comment: FYI, `HttpWebRequest` is part of .NET, not part of C#

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.

First, you can set the relevant **Proxy** property of the relevant objects [inside your code directly](http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET) instead of falling back to the configuration XML; you can then selectively control the use of the proxy based on any factor you like.

Alternatively, you could try setting the **scriptLocation** [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to point at `http://localhost:8888/proxy.pac` and use Fiddler's **about:config** to set `fiddler.proxy.pacfile.usefileprotocol` to `false` and tick the Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections > Use PAC Script box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an another approach, by enabling trace listeners on System.Net? It is not as comfortable as using Fiddler, but it might be enough for sporadic debugging. For message logging, just System.Net should be sufficient, but there are more.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <!--<source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>-->
      <!--<source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>-->
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add
          name="System.Net"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
        />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```